# Can you set the Media module to only show specific images?

Tags: 7, media

I'm looking to use the media module on a site. Very impressed so far with it but there is one thing I need of it for it to be perfect.

I need it to only show certain images in the library, not every single image that has been uploaded. Is there any way of doing this that any one knows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for the same functionality for a while, I've been through the media browser code and there's nothing I'm afraid.

The best you can do is download the **dev** version of [Media Browser Plus](http://drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus) which now has support for a hierarchical folder structure for the media library.

It doesn't have any access control by default (that I can see) but you might be able to hook in and add some.

Answer (score 3):

Media module 2.x uses views in its media browser.  You can edit the standard view, or create new ones, and use relationships and (exposed) filters.

Answer (score 2):

What I did for that was to create a view of my files, and give it the appropriate relationship.

Then I re-wrote the output of the field linking it to the fid/edit page of the file.

Also assigned the view as a menu in my admin bar. Was a pretty nifty solution.